# How to share input between popup and screen in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to "send" input2 from class `Create` to class(screen) `All`. For example I could method which add label with `text = input2`. How to do it?

> **My .py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
import sys
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.clipboard import Clipboard
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.graphics import RoundedRectangle, Color
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size=(400,600)
Window.clearcolor = (214/255, 201/255, 78/255, 1)
#TODO:JSONSTORE,LAYOUT,IF TIME:GRAPHICAL NOTES
#FIX SIZE_HINT AND POS_HINT

class MainWindow(Screen, FloatLayout):
    def submit(self):
        self.manager.current = "all"
class Create(Popup):
    input1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    input2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    def clear(self):
        self.input1.text = ""
        self.input2.text = ""
    def give(self, *args):
        name = (self.input2.text + ".json")
        if self.input2.text:
            with open(name, 'w') as fp:
                store = JsonStore(name)
            store['001'] = {self.input2.text:self.input1.text}
              
            
class All(Screen,FloatLayout):
    def opening(self):
        crt = Create()
        crt.open()
    def test(self):
        print("Worked")
    def closing(self):
        crt = Create()
        crt.dismiss()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(All, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Note(Screen, FloatLayout):
    pass

class Notes(App):
    title = "NOTES"
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("001.kv")
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name="main"))
        sm.add_widget(All(name="all"))
        sm.add_widget(Note(name="note"))
        return sm
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Notes().run()
```

> **My .kv:**

```
<MainWindow>:
    name:"main"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba : 255,255,255,1
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos:(95, 450)
            size : 210,120
            radius: [30, 30, 30, 30]
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text:"NOTES"
            pos:(100,450)
            size_hint:(.5,.2)
            color:0,0,0,1
        Label:
            text: "simple"
            pos:(100,425)
            size_hint:(.5,.2)
            color:0,0,0,1
        Button:
            text:"ALL NOTES"
            pos :(100, 180)
            size_hint : (.5,.2)
            on_release:app.root.current="all"
        Button:
            text:"EXIT"
            pos :(100, 60)
            size_hint : (.5,.2)
            on_release:app.stop()
<Create>:
    title:"ADD"
    input1:input1
    input2:input2
    size_hint: .5,.8
    auto_dismiss:True
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        pos:self.pos
        size:root.size
        TextInput:
            id:input2
            size_hint: 1,.1
            multiline: False
            hint_text:"Your note name here"
        TextInput:
            id:input1
            multiline: True
            hint_text:"Your note here"
        Button:
            id:save 
            text:"SAVE"
            size_hint:1,.2
            on_release:root.give()

            
        
<All>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text:"back"
            size_hint:(1,.2)
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"top":.2}
            on_release:app.root.current="main"
        Button:
            background_color: (214/255, 201/255, 78/255, 0)
            text: '+'
            on_release:root.opening()
            size_hint:(.2,.1)
            pos_hint:{"x":.8,"top":1}
        Button:
            background_color: (214/255, 201/255, 78/255, 0)
            text: 'INFO'
            size_hint:(.2,.1)
            pos_hint:{"x":.6,"top":1}
<Note>:
    name:"note"
    input3 : input3
    input4 : input4
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text:"NOTE NAME:"
            pos_hint:{"x":0.07,"top":.95}
            size_hint : (.1,0.05)
        TextInput:
            id : input3
            multiline:True
            pos_hint :{"x":.1,"top":.8}
            size_hint : (.8,.4)
        TextInput:
            id:input4
            multiline : False
            pos_hint:{"x":.25,"top":.95}
            size_hint:(.4,0.05)
        Button:
            id:"submit"
            text:"SAVE"
            pos_hint :{"x":.25,"top":.4}
            size_hint : (.5,.2)
            on_release:
                app.root.current="all"
                root.manager.get_screen("All").test()
                root.manager.get_screen("All").closing()




        Button:
            id:"back"
            text:"BACK"
            pos_hint :{"x":.25,"top":.2}
            size_hint : (.5,.2)
            on_release:app.root.current="main"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class All(Screen,FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(All, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.crt = Create()
    def opening(self):
        self.crt.open()
    def test(self):
        print(self.crt.input2.text)
    def closing(self):
        self.crt.dismiss()
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I call it from popup in .kv

Comment: And your didn't works, it write me error:   File "c:/Users/michal.DESKTOP-ILLSOPR/Desktop/PycharmProjects/VisualCode - folder/KIVY/001.py", line 44, in test
     print(self.crt.input2.text)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'